# Sending multicast over VPN (with buffering)

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, multicast

I am trying to connect two sites using VPN (OpenVPN) to transmit multicasts (IPTV) from one site to another. I have created a layer2 VPN and it works, however, multicasts are very sensitive to packet loss on the network and I inevitably have some packet loss, especially during peak times.

The device (IP to DVB-C mux) on the end has to receive multicasts (or udp or rtp unicasts), but I can use whatever I want on the tunnel itself.

I tried using ffmpeg to convert multicast to HLS on one end and then back to udp unicast on the other end, however, the unicast created by ffmpeg is too jittery and some DVB-C receivers do not like it.

Is there some other way to buffer the multicast so I can send it reliably over the tunnel with no jitter or stream corruption?

Comment: Have you considered using vlc or vls?

Comment: if you don't control your network endpoints, you can't control the jitter or data stream integrity. Do you control your network endpoints?

Comment: Yes, I control the network endpoints, but not the network in between (let's say it's two networks connected over the internet via VPN)